# Why doesn't my pressure relief valve work as expected?

Tags: water, heater

My water heater is 4 years old.  I noticed very hot water coming out of all faucets, no cold water and a whistling noise.  Added a regulator to stop back flow on cold water. Replaced pressure relief valve, all faucets start to leak. NEW Pressure relief valve started to leak- replaced it again, now that one leaks too!
Have a pressure reducer to reduce water pressure coming into the house on main line- set at 60 PSI.

There is an exchanger that sits on top of the water heater for in floor heat.
Can someone PLEASE tell my why my pressure releif valve will not work?  I am on the third one in three week.  I have also been through 3 water heaters in ten years.  HELP!

Comment: You tell us a number of things without context. It would be very difficult to troubleshoot with this small window into your apparently complex plumbing. A diagram or a more careful description seem in order.

Comment: First welcome to StackExchange, and yes, it is unclear what you're asking because more detail about your system needs to be filled in for us to understand it.  When you're looking at your own plumbing, it's easy to think "this system is surely typical, why describe details common to every house?" But in fact different installations can be quite different, and some can be different-as-in-defective,

Comment: Is the temperature regulating properly?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need an expansion tank for the hot water system. When you heat water, it expands. If there's no place for it to go, the pressure will rise until something gives. You might also need to adjust (or replace) the thermostat(s) on the water heater.

A PRV acts also as a check valve so 60 PSI into the house going cold into the water heater can then become a much higher pressure when the cold water is heated, if no valves are open using water. The new check valve (which you call a regulator, but I'm betting it's not) does the same thing closer to the water heater.